# Lumen with Mail - Unable to resolve NULL driver for [Illuminate\Mail\TransportManager]

Tags: php, email, lumen

I'm trying to send emails from Lumen 5.7, so as mentioned by many sources, I ..

1. added `illuminate/mail` and `guzzlehttp/guzzle` to my application
2. created "config/mail.php" and "config/services.php" from [Laravel Repository](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/config)
3. uncommented `$app->withFacades();`, registered `Illuminate\Mail\MailServiceProvider::class` and added `$app->configure('services');` and `$app->configure('mail');` before `return $app;` in `bootstrap/app.php`
4. added mailgun settings to `.env`

   MAIL_DRIVER=mailgun

   MAILGUN_DOMAIN=ssss

   MAILGUN_SECRET=xxxxx
5. tried to send an email `Mail::raw('Raw string email', function($msg) { $msg->to(['x@x.com']); $msg->from(['x@x.com']); });`

but still get this error message `Unable to resolve NULL driver for [Illuminate\Mail\TransportManager].`

P.S. This is my first experience with Lumen and I did search to resolve this problem for many hours, but I cannot.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have the same problem, and I can see that no answer is correct. Have you solved your problem?

Comment: Alright I've fixed mine.... I stupidly put `$app->configure('mail');` after `return $app`, which seems not in your case.

Answer (score 2):

If the config folder is in the "app" folder, then remove the "config" folder to the "main folder". it works for me.
Use mail base config from Laravel (config/mail.php), sorry to take your words ribrow :v

Comment: provides proper explanation of question.

Answer (score 1):

Use mail base config from Laravel (`config/mail.php`)

```
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Mail Driver
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Laravel supports both SMTP and PHP's "mail" function as drivers for the
    | sending of e-mail. You may specify which one you're using throughout
    | your application here. By default, Laravel is setup for SMTP mail.
    |
    | Supported: "smtp", "sendmail", "mailgun", "mandrill", "ses",
    |            "sparkpost", "log", "array"
    |
    */

    'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'smtp'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | SMTP Host Address
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may provide the host address of the SMTP server used by your
    | applications. A default option is provided that is compatible with
    | the Mailgun mail service which will provide reliable deliveries.
    |
    */

    'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.mailgun.org'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | SMTP Host Port
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This is the SMTP port used by your application to deliver e-mails to
    | users of the application. Like the host we have set this value to
    | stay compatible with the Mailgun e-mail application by default.
    |
    */

    'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Global "From" Address
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | You may wish for all e-mails sent by your application to be sent from
    | the same address. Here, you may specify a name and address that is
    | used globally for all e-mails that are sent by your application.
    |
    */

    'from' => [
        'address' => env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS', 'hello@example.com'),
        'name' => env('MAIL_FROM_NAME', 'Example'),
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | E-Mail Encryption Protocol
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may specify the encryption protocol that should be used when
    | the application send e-mail messages. A sensible default using the
    | transport layer security protocol should provide great security.
    |
    */

    'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | SMTP Server Username
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | If your SMTP server requires a username for authentication, you should
    | set it here. This will get used to authenticate with your server on
    | connection. You may also set the "password" value below this one.
    |
    */

    'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME'),

    'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Sendmail System Path
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | When using the "sendmail" driver to send e-mails, we will need to know
    | the path to where Sendmail lives on this server. A default path has
    | been provided here, which will work well on most of your systems.
    |
    */

    'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Markdown Mail Settings
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | If you are using Markdown based email rendering, you may configure your
    | theme and component paths here, allowing you to customize the design
    | of the emails. Or, you may simply stick with the Laravel defaults!
    |
    */

    'markdown' => [
        'theme' => 'default',

        'paths' => [
            resource_path('views/vendor/mail'),
        ],
    ],

];
```

And don't forget to install dependency

```
composer require guzzlehttp/guzzle
```

Comment: Thank you ribrow for your answer, I've already tried what you suggested as I mentioned in my question.

Answer (score 1):

I was having this same error and tried many solutions with no positive results.

What I did was replace the config/mail.php with this code and it worked. Using Lumen 6.0.

```
<?php
return [
  "driver" => "smtp",
  "host" => "smtp.mailtrap.io",
  "port" => 2525,
  "from" => array(
      "address" => "from@example.com",
      "name" => "Example"
  ),
  "username" => "user...",
  "password" => "....",
  "sendmail" => "/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs"
];
```

And another thing you might want to consider is to make sure that your illuminate/mail package matches the laravel/lumen-framework version. (6.0 in my case)